# Exclude one single column from sapply

Tags: r, sapply

I have a dataframe with multiple columns that I want to group according to their names. When several columns names respond to the same pattern, I want them grouped in a single column and that column is the sum of the group.

```
colnames(dataframe)

[1] "Départements" "01...3"       "01...4"       "01...5"       "02...6"       "02...7"       "02...8"       "02...9"       "02...10"      "03...11"     
 [11] "03...12"      "03...13"      "04...14"      "04...15"      "05...16"      "05...17"      "05...18"      "06...19"      "06...20"      "06...21"
```

So I use this bit of code that works just fine when every column are numeric, though the first one is character and therefore I hit an error. How can I exclude the first column from the code?

#Group columns by patern, look for a pattern and loop through

```
patterns <- unique(substr(names(dataframe_2012), 1, 3))`  #store patterns in a vector

dataframe <- sapply(patterns, function(xx) rowSums(dataframe[,grep(xx, names(dataframe)), drop=FALSE]))  
#loop through
```

This is the error code I get

> Error in rowSums(DEPTpolicedata_2012[, grep(xx, names(DEPTpolicedata_2012)),  :
> 'x' must be numeric

Comment: Sorry the error code according to the example is Error in rowSums(dataframe[, grep(xx, names(dataframe)), : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: What are the data type of each column in `dataframe`? It feels like some columns are non-numeric.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply remove the first column using

```
patterns$Départements <- NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. But it just returns
Error in patterns[, -1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: You're right indeed... It's FALSE all the way when I store the patterns in a vector. However in the original df, only the first column is character.

Comment: I have updated the answer, so you can remove the first column.

Comment: Maybe the problem is just that the vector pattern is simply character values. It should specify somehow how to get numeric values except in column 1